# C++: Separating a char* with '\t' delimiter

Tags: c++, boost

I've been fighting this problem for a while now, and can't seem to find a simple solution that doesn't involve parsing a char * by hand. I need to split my char* variable by '\t', and I've tried the following ways:

Method 1:

```
  char *splitentry;
  std::string ss;

  splitentry = strtok(read_msg_.data(), "\\t");
  while(splitentry != NULL)
  {
    std::cout << splitentry << std::endl;
    splitentry = strtok(NULL, "\\t");
  }
```

Using the input '\tthis\tis\ta\ttest'
results in this output:

```
his
is
a
es
```

Method 2:

```
std::string s(read_msg_.data());

boost::algorithm::split(strs, s, boost::is_any_of("\\t");
for (int i = 0; i < strs.size(); i++)
  std::cout << strs.at(i) << std::endl;
```

Which creates an identical output.
I've tried using boost::split_regex and used "\\t" as my regex value, but nothing gets split. Will I have to split it on my own, or am I going about this incorrectly?

Comment: `"\\t"` is the two characters backslash and t.  `"\t"` is the single character horizontal tab.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to make things a little simpler by sticking to `std::` functions. (p.s. you never use this: `std::string ss;`)

Why not do something like this?

Method 1: `std::istringstream`

```
std::istringstream ss(read_msg_.data());
std::string line;
while( std::getline(ss,line,ss.widen('\t')) )
    std::cout << line << std::endl;
```

Method 2: `std::string::substr` (my preferred method as it is lighter)

```
std::string data(read_msg_.data());
std::size_t SPLITSTART(0); // signifies the start of the cell
std::size_t SPLITEND(0);   // signifies the end of the cell
while( SPLITEND != std::string::npos ) {
    SPLITEND = data.find('\t',SPLITSTART);
    // SPLITEND-SPLITSTART signifies the size of the string
    std::cout << data.substr(SPLITSTART,SPLITEND-SPLITSTART) << std::endl;
    SPLITSTART = SPLITEND+1;
}
```